# I am cloning a django project from git but it is showing the following error

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Project to run:
https://github.com/anuj-glitch/Disease-Prediction-using-Django-and-machine-learning

[image: Error Log]

I tried running the command `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I think you need to create a postgres database, and change the project's settings ('NAME', 'USER', 'PASSWORD') according to what you have created.

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned the repo, your `DATABASES` setting in `settings.py` will look like this

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'predico',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

This means you need to set up a local postgres db with those credentials. try https://www.guru99.com/download-install-postgresql.html.

Unless this repo is using a postgres specifc feature, you can try using sqlite to get up and running faster.

```py
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just see the django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/

You may configure postgreSQL or You can also use the db that you have by changing a line in settings.py, For example if you have mysql db you can change the code as:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
}
}
```

or

You can use a database backend that doesn’t ship with Django by setting ENGINE to a fully-qualified path (i.e. mypackage.backends.whatever).